# TextView above Image view in a layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using this layout for my screen:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/tmp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/uph" 
        android:layout_gravity="top|center" android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/propfile" 
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

and i want to add a TextView to the screen that will be above the imageView2.

and when i add it to the xml it show it under the image.
what i need to do to be able to put `TextView` on image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/tmp" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/uph" 
             android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="top|center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/propfile" 
            />

           <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:text="text" 
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           /> 
      </RelativeLayout>   
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another LinearLayout where the second image is, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/tmp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/uph" 
        android:layout_gravity="top|center" android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Goes Here" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/propfile" 
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>    
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative, 
in your xml file,

```
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="text" 
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:layout_above="idofyourImage"
       />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: android:layout_above is not valid in a LinearLayout.