# Place view on top and between two views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-view

Trying to figure out to overcome this little problem.

Below, on the left side, is a sample of the view that I'm trying to implement for an app. On the right side is the view that I'm ending up with.
[image: Container]

In my xml mock up I've decided to use a `RelativeLayout` but I can't get the `TextView` to be centered between the top and bottom views.

For reference here's a represenation of my xml code:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width:"match_parent"
    android:layout_height:"wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BlackImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alightParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/RedImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BlackImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BlackImage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea what I'm missing, or how to change to get what I want?

Comment: I think I'd try a `FrameLayout` for that, because the `RelativeLayout` is rather used for views that are aligned along their edges. Anyhow, you could try a negative margin or padding.

Comment: try below link hope it will help you :-

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539772/textview-above-image-view-in-a-layout>

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976292/android-listview-item-display-text-over-image-using-array-adapter>

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195557/how-to-put-text-under-image-view>

Answer (score 0):

try below link hope it will help you :-

[TextView above Image view in a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539772/textview-above-image-view-in-a-layout)

[Android listview item display text over image using array adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976292/android-listview-item-display-text-over-image-using-array-adapter)

[how to put text under image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195557/how-to-put-text-under-image-view)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/tmp" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/uph" 
             android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"/>

        <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="top|center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/propfile" 
            />

           <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:text="text" 
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           /> 
      </RelativeLayout>   
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't know I could have multiple options for `layout_gravity`. You learn something new everyday! Gonna try this out, thanks for the link!